# Replace a specific symbol in the end of yyyy-MM-dd pattern using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, date

I have a string, which contains dates in `yyyy-MM-dd` format along with other symbols.
Some of these dates contains the `'Z'` symbol at the end.

For example:

```
control1970-04-26Z_shifted1982-02-01_Zulu1999-09-09Z
```

I need to eliminate these 'Z' symbols in the string and I guess regex would be a nice solution.

I've tried the following regex:

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}Z{1}
```

But it matches the whole date, include `'Z'` character.

Is there any way to match only `'Z'` character and eliminate it using `replaceAll` method?

Comment: Note that the Z stems from **zoned date time** where `Z` stands for zero, UTC, Greenwich mean time, +0:00. If you receive a Z, also +3:00 or -6:00 might be expected. [`LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) would give such a date. In a pattern `X` would match the zone offset with a possible 'Z'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a capturing group  and replace with the placeholder to the value stored in this group:

```
String result = s.replaceAll("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})Z", "$1");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FAtDvT/1). Here, `(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})` is a capturing group due to the pair of unescaped parentheses, its value is stored in Group 1. `Z` is just matched. When we replace the match with `$1`, the date is pasted back into the resulting string and `Z` is discarded.

Note that if you want to make sure you only match four digits that are not preceded with another digit, prepend the pattern with `(?<!\\d)`.

If you want to make sure there are no other letters after `Z`, you may append `(?![a-zA-Z])` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: great thanks for the detailed response, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

To replace part of a string based on what comes before it, use a *positive lookbehind*:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})Z", "");
```

See more on *lookarounds* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups).